# angular ng-repeat dynamic generate checkbox and string

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that host a template that takes in a JSON (that contain some data for building a table, and some method to manipulate the data) and generate a table.

relevant code in the template:

```
 <table class="table" id="table_{{table.name}}">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="header in table.headers track by $index">{{header}}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="row in table.rows track by $index">
            <td ng-repeat="item in row track by $index"
                ng-Click="table.selectedRow(row)">
               {{item}}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

an example of a json being fed into this template

```
$scope.searchTable = {
    headers: ["title", "deleted"],
    rows: [ ["ABC", true],
            ["DEF", false] ],
    [...]

}
```

My question is:

sometimes the table require a column with checkboxs, depending on the data. Is there any way to change my template so that when necessary it will generate a column of checkbox instead of just string?

For example: For the JSON example above, let's say I want the column of `deleted` to be checkboxes. So if an entry is deleted that row will have a unchecked checkbox under the `deleted` column.

Does this make any sense? Everything is generated dynamic, so I have no idea which column will be checkboxes. It all depends on the data the page gets from the server. So in the example: the server will tell client which entry is readable, then I will generate that JSON and feed it to the template. How should I structure my JSON and the template

Is this even doable? Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <tr ng-repeat="row in table.rows track by $index">
          <td ng-repeat="item in row track by $index">
          <div data-ng-if="item.type!=='checkbox'" ng-Click="table.selectedRow(row)"></div>
          <div data-ng-if="item.type==='checkbox'"> <input type="checkbox" /></div>

               {{item}}
            </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Np) Mark as answer pls)

Comment: There is a time limit, have to wait before I can check an answer

Comment: Didnt know. Thanks!